# Using Gaussian elimination for a parametric solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

On several occasions I've seen involving Gaussian elimination to solve a system of equations, while this method doesn't seem to add anyting to the process, and the system must be solved using regular algebraic inference.

E.g. from *example 4.11.12* [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Linear_Algebra/A_First_Course_in_Linear_Algebra_(Kuttler)/04%3A_R/4.11%3A_Orthogonality#Example_.5C(.5CPageIndex.7B12.7D.5C):%20_Orthogonal_Complement):

[image]

As you can see there is no additional explanation about how Gaussian elimination is further conducted. My understanding is Gaussian elimination is not used at all, the solution $t \, (1, -2, 1)$ is just found from the equation system:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_{1}-x_{3} & =0\\
x_{2}+2x_{3} & =0
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x_{1} & =x_{3}\\
x_{2} & =-2x_{3}
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow
(x_{1,}x_{2,}x_{3})=t\,(1,-2,1)
$$

But I'm not sure. What does the textbook wanted to say by "using Gaussian elimination" in this example?

Comment: The identity function may not seem particularly profound but it is a function. This gives me the same vibe where sometimes the thing you're doing is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

For most 2x2 or 2x3 systems of equations, simple algebra **is** the way to go. But for larger systems, GE is a very helpful **methodical** approach to solving them. Book-authors often want to get you used to the idea that when you see a linear system, you bring out the standard tool (GE) to solve it. This isn't a great example, I admit, but writing a 4 x 6 example would have taken a lot of space, and all the steps of GE would have occupied more, etc.

One thing you get from GE is that at some point you may have an all-zero row in the main block, but a nonzero number in the far right; if that happens, you know your equations are inconsistent and there's no solution and you can stop working.

Another is that when you're done with GE, on the left you have a row-reduced matrix and perhaps $k$ of the rows have leading 1's, and $n-k$ do not. If the right-hand side of your system was all zeros, this tells you that you have an $n-k$-dimensional space of solutions to your system; if the right-hand side was nonzero, then it tells you that if there is *any* solution, then there is an $n-k$-parameter family of solutions. Those observations do not always instantly arise when you have 7 equations in 11 variables scribbled all over your page.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to use GJE and how it is useful, but I don't understand the sentence "*Using Gaussian Elimination, we find that …*" in the present example, as actually it seems it doesn't help at all, since in the end for parametric solutions, after RREF is obtained, then classical algebra is required to extract the solution. It seems you confirm that, right?

Comment: Well...no. It all depends on the part you didn't quote. If that part says "we find that the solution space is one-dimensional", then that's much simpler than actually writing out the parametric description of the solution space. If it says "we find that ..." and then gives your equations, then maybe yes. Either way, this isn't really a mathematics question, it's an "authorial intent" question. I probably should have just said nothing.

Comment: I added a snapshot of the linked page, as you can see there is no explanation at all, only the final solution.

Comment: Ah..so it's just what I thought. The author wants you to get good at looking at the row-reduced matrix (which this one happens to already be), observe that $x_3$ is a free variable, and substitute in $x_3 = 1$ (and thus determine $x_2$ and $x_1$ by negating the entries in the 3rd column (3rd because "$x_3$")), and that this constitutes a basis for the orthogonal complement --- the idea here is to get you used to the idea that reading off bases from the result of GE is a basic skill the author'll be assuming from now on. (Or at least that's what it'd be all about if **I** had written it.)

Comment: I see now, I didn't understand how to use the free-variable column(s) in the RREF to get the final result. Perhaps you could include this in your answer, it was the main difficulty for me.